# PreviewView isn't available in my AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I am attempting to implement a basic camera application using a PreviewView. However, in my android studio, PreviewViews aren't listed. Any suggestions as to how to find it? Or potential workarounds?

[PreviewView not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLZAU.png)

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8y6n.png)

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: Hi, I had trouble understanding your question PreviewViews arent listed ... can you describe more w.r.t this ? Please elaborate your question and explain what error are you getting exactly ?

Comment: @AgentP the problem is that PreviewViews are not listed in the possible layout components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add camera-view dependency in your build.gradle file like this

```
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha26'
```

Comment: I added this dependency, as shown in screenshots now. However, PreviewView still not found.

Comment: Have you seen anything like that before ? Or you are assuming that it should appear like all other views ? Cause I havent used anything like that before ...

Comment: Had seen an example online about using them as a layout component, however now believe it was a frame layout, then they used the PreviewView constructor separately. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView

Comment: Yeah... I guess they might just used frame layout and just modified code afterwards ... You can just do what they did ... I mean by code